# Add backgroud and font color on html page using java

Tags: java, html

I have below code to generate the html page after test execution, now I want to change the backgroud color and font color of tags. Please help how to do it.

Data is picked from data.js file which is a Json file.  Where and how can I change the colors on html page in below code?

```
public class MailComponent {

    public static String getHTMLBody() {
        try {
            JSONObject testData = (JSONObject) Control.ReportManager.pHandler.getData();
            File file = new File(FilePath.getMailReportTemplatePath(), "mailBody.html");
            String str = FileUtils.readFileToString(file, Charset.defaultCharset());

            str = str.replace("{releaseName}", testData.get("releaseName").toString()).
                    replace("{testSetName}", testData.get("testsetName").toString()).
                    replace("{parallelThreads}", testData.get("maxThreads").toString()).
                    replace("{runConfig}", testData.get("runConfiguration").toString()).
                    replace("{startTime}", testData.get("startTime").toString()).
                    replace("{endTime}", testData.get("endTime").toString()).
                    replace("{totalDuration}", testData.get("exeTime").toString()).
                    replace("{passedTests}", testData.get("nopassTests").toString()).
                    replace("{failedTests}", testData.get("nofailTests").toString());

            StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
                     for (Object tc : (JSONArray) testData.get("EXECUTIONS")) {
                JSONObject json = (JSONObject) tc;
                html.append("</tr>")
                        .append("<td>").append(json.get("scenarioName")).append("</td>\n")
                        .append("<td>").append(json.get("testcaseName")).append("</td>\n")
                        .append("<td>").append(json.get("browser")).append("</td>\n")
                        .append("<td>").append(json.get("exeTime")).append("</td>\n")
                        .append("<td>").append(json.get("status")).append("</td>\n")
                        .append("<td>").append(json.get("bversion")).append("</td>\n")
                        .append("<td>").append(json.get("platform")).append("</td>\n")
                        .append("<td>").append(json.get("iterations")).append("</td>\n")
                        .append("</tr>");
            }
            str = str.replace("{reportData}", html.toString());
            return str;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MailComponent.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, append the color attribute and its value into your String object.

Answer (score 0):

Append the color or background color attribute and its value into your String object

Example : This one will set the background color to red for this td

```
 a.append("<td bgcolor='red'").append(json.get("scenarioName")).append("</td>\n")
```

Comment: HOW TO DO IT FOR A THIS PARTICULAR TAG RATHER THAN bg COLOR